# Is the async/await transformation process specified?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, specifications

In C#, the process for transforming LINQ query syntax into the actual code that gets executed is described in great detail in section 7.16 of the language specification, which makes it simple for a language developer to use it to implement similar query syntax on a new CLR language.

Is there any similarly detailed specification for the async/await syntax added in C# version 5?  One of Eric Lippert's blog posts on the subject shows [a before-and-after view of the transformation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/01/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-three-composition.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) in a certain scenario, but that doesn't actually reveal the underlying rules in any useful level of detail. Does the specification for this exist somewhere?

EDIT: I can see that there's a section about await expressions and async functions in the C# language specification.  It doesn't go into anywhere near the same level of detail as the LINQ section does, though.  Essentially what I'm looking for is a process description that says "follow these steps to transform the code at the top of Eric's post into the state machine at the bottom of the post," such that a language designer could implement the feature in a different CLR language and end up having the same semantics.

Comment: Well... it's described in §7.7.7 and §10.15 of the spec (especially §7.7.7.3).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Yes, I've seen that, but the specification there is nowhere near as detailed as the description of the LINQ transformations.

Comment: The more obvious transformation to look at is iterator blocks/`yield` (indeed, they've reused a lot of those moving parts) and these similarly seem to not have an explicit mechanism specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a implementation detail as it tends to change. E.g. c#6 will introduce await in catch/finally clauses (the idea in general described [here](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Lowering/AsyncRewriter/AsyncExceptionHandlerRewriter.cs#45)).

However, [there are](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/12/23/c-async-and-await-a-deeper-dive.aspx) some deep-dive details about how awaiters are implemented in c#5. Look at links, especially this: [Async Codegen](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-12-06-TalkAsync2013/8713.Async-Codegen-_5B00_slides_5D00_-_2D00_-Lucian-Wischik-_2D00_-MS-internal-2011.10.11.pptx) (ppt).

> Such that a language designer could implement the feature in a different CLR language and end up having the same semantics

I'd recommend to look at AsyncRewriter [code](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Lowering/AsyncRewriter/AsyncRewriter.cs#41).